# Is enough to evaluate the limits at the edges of the domain to determine the range of $y = 5/(x^3+2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is enough to evaluate the limits at the edges of the domain in order to determine the range of $y = 5/(x^3+2)$?

The domain is $(-\infty, -2^{1/3}) \cup (-2^{1/3}, +\infty)$ and calculating the limits at the edges of the domain, I obtain: $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,+\infty)$, which is the range. But I've checked it in a calculator and would like to understand if in this case I need more information in order to state the range. For instance, taking the derivative (I've done it) ed evaluate if/where the function decreases/increases… However, would like to know more from you, concerning this specific case and in general!

Comment: the limits by themselves tell you nothing

Comment: Please also continue to learn to use LaTeX, here the symbols `\cap` $\cap$ and `\cup` $\cup$.

Comment: could you add some more info. Perhaps, answering to the question, please?

Comment: I had to learn how to use LaTex for an exam of AI some years ago but forgot it...yes, I will try to find the time for this too:)

Comment: Then please add further specifications to the task. Because of the pole, you correctly got $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$ as range. For that there is nothing more needed.

Comment: Ok, so probably this is the answer but I don't know what is the pole. Checking now....

Comment: The pole is the singularity at $x=-\sqrt[3\,]2$.

Comment: do you mean that if we find the vertical asymptote, there isn't anything relevant more as for determining the range, right? (I mean, if we find the singularity, namely the point in which is located the vertical asymptote).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31178/discussion-between-always-learning-and-lutzl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a rational function $$ f = P(x)/Q(x), \quad f : I \subseteq \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$ as in your case, you have that $ f$ is continuous on $ I = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : x \text { is not a root of } Q(x) \}$.

Furthermore, in your case $$ f'(x) = -15x^2/(x^3 +2 ) \le 0 \text{ for every }x \in I$$ thus $ f$ is monotonic decreasing in $ I $.

Thus it is enough to calculate the limits at the edges of $ I $ to determine the range of $ f $ since:

- the function is monotonic and thus it will have his maximum and minimum values on the edges of $ I $;
- the function is continuous on its domain and thus "it will not have holes" between is maxima and minima values.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is decreasing over $(-\infty, -2^{1/3})$ and $(-2^{1/3}, +\infty)$, because $y'(x)\le0$. It is then enough to evaluate the limits at the endpoints of the domain to get its range.

In general, if $f$ is not monotonic, you also have to find its maxima and minima over every interval of continuity.

Comment: You don't need any derivative to see it is decreasing on each  interval.